# Conditional settings for Gulp plugins dependent on source file

Tags: node.js, gulp, node-streams

The plugin `gulp-pug` allows to pass global variables to pug files via `data` property.
What if we don't need full data set in each `.pug` file? To implement conditional data injection, we need to access to current `vinyl` file instance inside `pipe(this.gulpPlugins.pug({})` or at least to know the source file absolute path. Possible?

```js
const dataSetForTopPage = {
    foo: "alpha",
    bar: "bravo"
};

const dataSetForAboutPage = {
    baz: "charlie",
    hoge: "delta"
};


gulp.src(sourceFileGlobsOrAbsolutePath)
    .pipe(gulpPlugins.pug({
      data: /* 
       if path is 'top.pug' -> 'dataSetForTopPage',  
       else if path is 'about.pug' -> 'dataSetForAboutPage'
       else -> empty object*/
    }))
    .pipe(Gulp.dest("output"));
```

I am using [gulp-intercept](https://github.com/khilnani/gulp-intercept#readme) plugin. But how to synchronize it with `gulpPlugins.pug`?

```js
gulp.src(sourceFileGlobsOrAbsolutePath)
    .pipe(this.gulpPlugins.intercept(vinylFile => {
      // I can compute conditional data set here
      // but how to execute gulpPlugins.pug() here?
    }))
    // ...
```

It was just one example, but we will deal with same problem when need to conditional plugins options for other gulp plugins, too. E. g:

```
.pipe(gulpPlugins.htmlPrettify({ 
  indent_char: " ", 
  indent_size: // if source file in 'admin/**' -> 2, else if in 'auth/**' -> 3 else 4
}))
```

Comment: Your questions seems a bit confusing to me, but I think it comes from not knowing what you're trying to do. In any case, if you want to conditionally control the stream, use [gulp-if](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if)

Comment: @JoshDavenport, sorry for unclear question. AFAIK, gulp-if is being used for the cases when we need to decide, should execute some plugin or no (e.g. `.pipe(gulpIf(booleanVariable, gulpPug({})))`. Here is plugin will be always executed, but options depends on source file. E. g.: `.pipe(gulpPug({ data: /* this option must be computed in relation to source file absolute path */ })`. All I need to know is how to get source file absolute path inside `data: { /* here */ }`.

Comment: Right, I see, well you could have multiple gulp-if pipes calling the same plugin but with different options based on your conditions? Re-reading your question it seems like you essentially need options need the options to come dynamically from the pug data values you're referring to. Kinda seems like that would best be handled in your application somehow with your gulp build agnostic to that. Just a thought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to modify the stream manually - [through2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/through2) is probably the most used package for this purpose. Once in the through2 callback, you can pass the stream to your gulp plugins (as long as their transform functions are exposed) and conditionally pass them options. For example, here is a task:

```
pugtest = () => {
    const dataSet = {
        'top.pug': {
            foo: "alpha",
            bar: "bravo"
        },
        'about.pug': {
            foo: "charlie",
            bar: "delta"
        }
    };

    return gulp.src('src/**/*.pug')
        .pipe(through2.obj((file, enc, next) => 
            gulpPlugins.pug({
                // Grab the filename, and set pug data to the value found in dataSet by that name
                data: dataSet[file.basename] || {}
            })._transform(file, enc, next)
        ))
        .pipe(through2.obj((file, enc, next) => {
            const options = {
                indent_char: ' ',
                indent_size: 4
            };

            if(file.relative.match(/admin\//)) {
                options.indent_size = 2;
            } else if(file.relative.match(/auth\//)) {
                options.indent_size = 3;
            }

            file.contents = new Buffer.from(html.prettyPrint(String(file.contents), options), enc);
            next(null, file);
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('output'));
}
```

For the pug step, we call `through2.obj` and create the pug plugin, passing it data grabbed from our object literal, indexed by filename in this example. So now the data passed into the compiler comes from that object literal.

For the html step you mention, [gulp-html-prettify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-prettify) doesn't expose its transform function, so we can't reach into it and pass the transform back to the stream. But in this case that's OK, if you look at the source it's just a wrapper to `prettyPrint` in the [html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html) package. That's quite literally all it is doing. So we can just rig up our step using through2 to do the same thing, but changing our options based on the vinyl file's relative path.

That's it! For a working example see this repo: https://github.com/joshdavenport/stack-overflow-61314141-gulp-pug-conditional

Comment: You have created the repository for me? I don't know how to thank you because I understand the value of professional's time. Gratitude for canonical answer, code examples, explanations and repository. And of course, I'll give you the reputation points.

Comment: I've been getting fairly deep into some advanced gulp build pipelines recently, and trying to learn the intricacies of streams and how they can be modularised and altered. This looked like an interesting little challenge, so the repo is there for you just as much as it is for me. Didn't take long, so don't fret - in any case thanks for your kind words and the rep! :)